# Get uncommon elements from two list - KOTLIN

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I have two list of same model class (STUDENT), sample student object structure is given below,

```
{
  "_id": "5a66d78690429a1d897a91ed",
  "division": "G",
  "standard": "X",
  "section": "Secondary",
  "lastName": "Sawant",
  "middleName": "Sandeep",
  "firstName": "Shraddha",
  "pin": 12345,
  "isEditable": true,
  "isTracked": false
}
```

One list have 3 objects and other 2. lets say, List A has 1, 2, 3 students and List B has 1, 2

So my question is there any inbuilt functions to get the uncommon element **by comparing just the id**? If not how can i solve this issue.

FYI, following are the two approaches i have made to solve, but failed miserably.

Approach 1.

```
internal fun getDistinctStudents(studentsList: List<Students>, prefStudents: List<Students>): List<Students> {
    val consolidated = prefStudents.filter {
        prefStudents.any { students: Students -> it._id == students._id }
    }
    return prefStudents.minus(consolidated)
}
```

Approach 2.

```
internal fun getDistinctStudents(studentsList: List<Students>, prefStudents: List<Students>): List<Students> {
    val consolidatedStudents = studentsList + prefStudents
    val distinctStudents = consolidatedStudents.distinctBy{ it._id }
    return prefStudents.minus(distinctStudents)
}
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: consolidate the two Lists and then make a hashmap from String to Integer which is id of the student to the number of occurrences and then loop over the hashmap and get the keys which have only 1 occurrence.

Comment: You can create the map from Student to number of occurrences just to get the List of students in the end

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A more Kotlin way to achieve what Ahmed Hegazy posted. The map will contain a list of elements, rather than a key and count.

Using HashMap and Kotlin built-ins. `groupBy` creates a Map with a key as defined in the Lambda (id in this case), and a List of the items (List for this scenario)

Then filtering out entries that have a list size other than 1.

And finally, converting it to a single List of Students (hence the flatMap call)

```
val list1 = listOf(Student("1", "name1"), Student("2", "name2"))
val list2 = listOf(Student("1", "name1"), Student("2", "name2"), Student("3", "name2"))

val sum = list1 + list2
return sum.groupBy { it.id }
    .filter { it.value.size == 1 }
    .flatMap { it.value }
```

Comment: Nice solution! :)

Comment: Actually.. Yes.. This is a nice solution indeed,

Comment: KIS. Keep it simple. I loved it.

Answer (score 36):

I know that this is an old post but I believe there is a neater and shorter solution. See sample below using **Mikezx6r**'s data whose answer was accepted above.

```
val list1 = listOf(Student("1", "name1"), Student("2", "name2"))
val list2 = listOf(Student("1", "name1"), Student("2", "name2"), Student("3", "name2"))

val difference = list2.toSet().minus(list1.toSet())
```

Comment: This only works if you want elements from list2, that are not in list1. It is not a result of "distinct elements" of 2 lists. list1.toSet().minus(list2.toSet()) gives no elements, so be careful using this answer.

Answer (score 12):

If you have two lists, where element is identified e.g. by some kind of id (item.id), then you can do as below:

```
fisrtList.filter { it.id !in secondList.map { item -> item.id } }
```

I assume firstList and secondList contain objects of the same type naturally.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an extension function that basically does what you want. It makes an assumption that the element `E` knows how to be identified, e.g. by `Student._id` in your example:

```
infix fun <E> Collection<E>.symmetricDifference(other: Collection<E>): Set<E> {
    val left = this subtract other
    val right = other subtract this
    return left union right
}
```

Here's an example of how it could be used:

```
val disjunctiveUnion: List<Student> = listA symmetricDifference listB
```

An example test case I'd written for it:

```
@Test
fun `symmetric difference with one of either set`() {
    val left = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    val right = listOf(2, 3, 4)

    val result = left symmetricDifference right

    assertEquals(setOf(1, 4), result)
}
```

Comment: This is an awesome explanation! I have a case where I need to only remove the redundant elements from lets say left, e.g. from your example I want the result to be list of (1) where left is (1, 2, 3) and right is (2, 3, 4)

Answer (score 3):

Until someone comes up with a neater and shorter solution, here's a working one that I think is easy enough to read:

```
internal fun getDistinctStudents(studentsList: List<Students>, prefStudents: List<Students>): List<Students> {
    val studentsIds = studentsList.map { it._id }          // [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    val prefStudentIds = prefStudents.map { it._id }       // [ 1, 2 ]
    val commonIds = studentsIds.intersect(prefStudentIds)  // [ 1, 2 ]

    val allStudents = studentsList + prefStudents      // [ Student1, Student2, Student3, Student1, Student2 ]
    return allStudents.filter { it._id !in commonIds } // [ Student3 ]
}
```

---

If you have a very large amount of students (hundreds), consider using sequences for the various steps, and perhaps filtering before concatenating the last two lists could help too:

```
val filteredStudents = studentsList.filter { it._id !in commonIds }
val filteredPrefStudents = prefStudents.filter { it._id !in commonIds }
return filteredStudents + filteredPrefStudents
```

Edit: see [this answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48501654/4465208).

Comment: Will try and will let you know. Thanks for the effort. :)

Comment: Someone ended up posting a nice solution, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48501654/4465208)

Comment: I have found a solution.. Please check if its the right way to achieve it? Will totally appreciate if you could check the solution and point out if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution using a HashMap, the code could be better, but I'm very new to kotlin

```
fun getDistinctStudents(studentsList: List<Student>, prefStudents: List<Student>): List<Student> {
    val studentsOccurrences = HashMap<Student, Int>()
    val consolidatedStudents = studentsList + prefStudents
    for (student in consolidatedStudents) {
        val numberOfOccurrences = studentsOccurrences[student]
        studentsOccurrences.put(student, if(numberOfOccurrences == null) 1 else numberOfOccurrences + 1)
    }
    return consolidatedStudents.filter { student -> studentsOccurrences[student] == 1 }
}
```

Your student class should be a data class or at least overrides hashcode and equals to be used as a key.

Comment: Will try and will let you know. Thanks for the effort. :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally after some searching on Kotlin docs i have the solution. the function i was looking for was `filterNot`

Here is the complete solution which i tried.

```
internal fun getDistinctStudents(studentsList: List<Students>, prefStudents: List<Students>): List<Students> {
    return prefStudents.filterNot { prefStudent ->
         studentsList.any {
             prefStudent._id == it._id
         }
    } 
}
```

Which returned the uncommon elements.

Comment: This won't give you the students that are only in `studentsList`, only the ones that are only in `prefStudents`. I think you should stick to the solution by @Mikezx6r.

Answer (score 1):

On mobile right now so I can’t test it but this might work for what you need. 
Using subtract from stdlib https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/subtract.html

```
internal fun getDistinctStudents(studentsList: List<Students>, prefStudents: 
List<Students>): List<Students> {
    return prefStudents.subtract(studentList) + studentList.subtract(prefStudents)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, But by common objects i meant the student id only, only id can be same, rest all data can or might be different, so if i use subtract the case break if id is same and name is different.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry I was assuming Student was a data class and id/name were part of the primary constructor

Comment: No Issues bother.. Once again thanks for your effort. :)